# how to handle dates in sql in a large data set

Tags: sql-server

i am new to SQL I need help with syntax/ ideas to do below.

I have data in the table in the below format

```
PLANT   MATERIAL              COST          FROM
2461    000000000029060405   212.920    16-01-2017
2461    000000000029060405   217.301    17-03-2017
2461    000000000029060405   206.900    16-05-2017
2461    000000000029060405   210.400    15-07-2017
2461    000000000029060405   206.900    13-09-2017
2461    000000000029060405   210.400    12-11-2017
2461    000000000029060405   206.900    11-01-2018
2461    000000000029060405   210.400    10-07-2018
2461    000000000029060405   206.900    08-09-2018
2461    000000000029060405   210.400    07-11-2018
2461    000000000029060405   206.900    06-01-2019
2461    000000000029060405   210.400    07-03-2019
2461    000000000029060405   206.900    06-05-2019
2461    000000000029060405   206.900    01-01-2020
2461    000000000029060405   210.400    01-03-2020
```

I would want a syntax which can provide cost per month in the below format

```
PLANT   MATERIAL             COST       DATE
2462    000000000029060405   212.920    01-02-2017
2463    000000000029060405   212.920    02-02-2017
2464    000000000029060405   217.301    03-02-2017
2465    000000000029060405   217.301    04-02-2017
2466    000000000029060405   206.900    05-02-2017
2467    000000000029060405   206.900    06-02-2017
2468    000000000029060405   210.400    07-02-2017
2469    000000000029060405   210.400    08-02-2017
2470    000000000029060405   206.900    09-02-2017
2471    000000000029060405   206.900    10-02-2017
2472    000000000029060405   210.400    11-02-2017
2473    000000000029060405   210.400    12-02-2017
2474    000000000029060405   206.900    13-02-2017
2475    000000000029060405   206.900    14-02-2017
2476    000000000029060405   206.900    15-02-2017
2477    000000000029060405   206.900    16-02-2017
2478    000000000029060405   206.900    17-02-2017
2479    000000000029060405   206.900    18-02-2017
2480    000000000029060405   210.400    19-02-2017
2481    000000000029060405   210.400    20-02-2017
2482    000000000029060405   206.900    21-02-2017
2483    000000000029060405   206.900    22-02-2017
2484    000000000029060405   210.400    23-02-2017
2485    000000000029060405   210.400    24-02-2017
2486    000000000029060405   206.900    25-02-2017
2487    000000000029060405   206.900    26-02-2017
2488    000000000029060405   210.400    27-02-2017
2489    000000000029060405   210.400    28-02-2017
2490    000000000029060405   206.900    01-03-2017
2491    000000000029060405   206.900    02-03-2017
2492    000000000029060405   206.900    03-03-2017
2493    000000000029060405   206.900    04-03-2017
2494    000000000029060405   206.900    05-03-2017
2495    000000000029060405   206.900    06-03-2017
2496    000000000029060405   206.900    07-03-2017
2497    000000000029060405   206.900    08-03-2017
2498    000000000029060405   206.900    09-03-2017
2499    000000000029060405   206.900    10-03-2017
2500    000000000029060405   210.400    11-03-2017
2501    000000000029060405   210.400    12-03-2017
2502    000000000029060405   210.400    13-03-2017
2503    000000000029060405   210.400    14-03-2017
2504    000000000029060405   210.400    15-03-2017
2505    000000000029060405   210.400    16-03-2017
```

Comment: Are you really storing your dates as `varchar`?  Don't do that; use `timestamp` or something similar.

Comment: You really expect the reader to go through your data and analyze it? Please specify your problem clearly and provide a scatter-free sample of your data.

Comment: please elaborate the logic

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: In T-SQL timestamp is not a date format.

Comment: You want 'cost per month' but then every date is listed in your expected output? Does not make sense.

Comment: @Sefe Sorry...too much MySQL bad for brain...but you get my point hopefully

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess u want to group your data by Plant and date.Please try this code:

```
Select Plant,Material,Sum(Cost),Date
From Tablename 
Group By Plant,Material,Date
order by Date
```